# how to create a numpy matrix of 8*8

Tags: python, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to make a matrix of 8*8 , so i used this :

```
s=np.indices((8,8))
```

output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]])
```

However, I just want a single matrix that looks like the first one.

Comment: `numpy.zeros(shape=(8,8))` if you want an 8x8 matrix filled with 0s

Comment: What do you want the contents of this matrix to be?

Comment: the result should be like the first array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this:

1. Take the first element of your `np.indices()` result

```
np.indices((8,8))[0]
```

2. Repeat / tile the result of `np.arange()`

```
np.tile(np.arange(8), (8, 1)).T
```

3. Create an 8x8 array of zeros and add a column vector containing the numbers 0-7. Let broadcasting take care of the rest

```
np.zeros((8, 8)) + np.arange(8)[:, None]
# or 
(np.zeros((8, 8)) + np.arange(8)).T
```

4. Multiply a 8x1 column vector containing the numbers 0-7 with a row vector of eight ones. Also uses broadcasting

```
np.arange(8)[:, None] * np.ones((1, 8))
# or 
(np.ones((8, 1)) * np.arange(8)).T
```

All of these give the same result (save for `dtype` -- the first two return `int` arrays, the rest return `float` arrays, but changing the type is pretty easy anyway):

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
       [7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7., 7.]])
```

Finding which is the most efficient is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

try something like [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/matrix#:%7E:text=2.%20array%20of%20zeros%20and%20ones)?

```
import numpy as np

zeors_array = np.zeros( (8, 8) )
print(zeors_array)
```